# Remove value from string where it match another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove a file path from the beginning of a column. I have table with 3 columns one has just the path I want to remove.

So I have a table like:

[image]

Is there any way in SQL Server 2008 that I can remove the text where it matches the path column?

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question*, preferably as text.

Comment: The column contains paths to files as well as folders. Which ones you want to remove? Be specific and show the desired result.

Comment: Sorry it wont allow me to post screenshot. Basically I want remove all the text from the column [Dataconv] that matches the text in [Path]. So from the screenshot all that would be left for each row is Test Data, Test Data 2 etc       If its a folder structure and not a file I want to remove it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using replace?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, dataconv VARCHAR(500), [path] VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 'C:\windows test_data_1', 'C:\windows';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 'C:\windows\test.ini test_data_2', 'C:\windows\test.ini';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, 'C:\word docs\doc.ini test_data_3', 'C:\word docs\doc.ini';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4, '/P/TestUser/dfg002/SinglePageCV''s/JoeBloggs.doc33216root;tuser002_admin@IEroot;D‌​omain:Users@IE431104 1330820929 1003750078 1055597658', '/P/TestUser/dfg002/SinglePageCV''s/JoeBloggs.doc';
SELECT id, LTRIM(REPLACE(dataconv, [path], '')) FROM @table;
```

Returns:

```
1   test_data_1
2   test_data_2
3   test_data_3
4   33216root;tuser002_admin@IEroot;D??omain:Users@IE431104 1330820929 1003750078 1055597658
```

Comment: I tried that there and it remove it for some of the records but not for all. In some of the records there is no space after the file name so it could be C:\windowsTest_data_1 Would this cause issues with the replace?.

Comment: I can add another column with the length of the path I want to remove. ITs always at the beginning of the dataconv field. So could I do it that it removes the first x number of characters depending on whats in the length field.

Comment: REPLACE shouldn't care whether there are spaces or not, it just looks for a piece of text and then replaces it, in this case with nothing.  Maybe if you had an example of it not working?

Comment: Thats one row that it doesnt work on: Dataconv field is:  /P/TestUser/dfg002/SinglePageCV's/JoeBloggs.doc33216root;tuser002_admin@IEroot;Domain:Users@IE431104 1330820929 1003750078 1055597658

Comment: Path is:  /P/TestUser/dfg002/SinglePageCV's/JoeBloggs.doc

Comment: Works fine for me, possibly it's the single quotes in there causing problems?  But as you can see, I updated my answer to include your sample data (copied directly from the comments) and I had to replace single quotes with two single quotes, so "CV's" became "CV''s".  You shouldn't need to do this, as the data will already be in the database?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table x
SET x.dataconv = SUBSTRING(x.dataconv,LEN(x.path),LEN(x.dataconv))
WHERE SUBSTRING(x.dataconv,1,LEN(x.path)) == x.path
```